# Typescript Cannot assign type '{ [key: string]: string; }[]' to type 'T[]'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, type-conversion, typeerror, type-inference

I have an independent helper function which allows to filter an array of objects by string key:

```
function filterRows(
  rows: Array<{ [key: string]: string }>,
  searchKey: string
) {
  return rows.filter((obj) =>
    Object.keys(obj).some((key) => obj[key].toString().includes(searchKey))
  );
}
```

In a component, I have a variable **TableRowsCells** of type `Array<T>` (component infer type)

So, this variable can have value; examples:

```
const TableRowsCells = [
  {
    firstname: 'John',
    lastname: 'Adams'
  },
  {
    firstname: 'Paul',
    lastname: 'Walker'
  },
];
```

or

```
const TableRowsCells = [
  {
    company: 'Vody aho',
    nb_employees: 1590,
    country: 'Hong Kong'
  },
  {
    company: 'Royal spirit',
    nb_employees: 15,
    country: 'USA'
  },
];
```

Now i want to filter this variable using above helper function:

```
type EnhancedTableProps<T> = {
  TableRowsCells: Array<T>;
  searchKey?: string;
};

function EnhancedTable<T>({ TableRowsCells, searchKey }: EnhancedTableProps<T>) {
  /** Code stuff...**/

  let outputRowsItems = TableRowsCells;
  if (typeof searchKey === 'string' && searchKey.length > 2) {
    outputRowsItems = filterRows(TableRowsCells, searchKey);
  }

  /** Code stuff...**/
}
```

Like this, I have 2 errors for typescripts:

**Error 1 (`outputRowsItems = filterRows(TableRowsCells, searchKey);` in outputRowsItems):**

```
Cannot assign type '{ [key: string]: string; }[]' to type 'T[]'.
  Cannot assign type '{ [key: string]: string; }' to type 'T'.
    'T' could have been instantiated with an arbitrary type which may not be related to '{ [key: string]: string; }'.ts(2322)
```

**Error 2 (`outputRowsItems = filterRows(TableRowsCells, searchKey);` in TableRowsCells ):**

```
(parameter) TableRowsCells: T[]
Argument of type 'T[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ [key: string]: string; }[]'.
  Cannot assign type 'T' to type '{ [key: string]: string; }'.ts(2345)
```

At the end, I want `outputRowsItems` to have the same type as `TableRowsCells` i.e. `Array<T>`

Could you please help me to solve these errors?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAkFMBsAdIE4DoAuBnAHgKGAKlJBrAPYIqi5gBmArgHYDGKAlsXaFc9CogErEB3NAAosoUAkFoAXKACCCBAEMAngB4A3qADaAa0grZaFAmZ0A5gF0jJs+dABfAHwAaMaDSQlCBgAsA0gY2phZYAJSgGu4IkCg0COySQkic3IjCwsQARgBWEQC8Tu7iAPK5kExI+ioi2XlIaMQAtpAZ1QVOoHV6BpaoxADKthbCYUhmDNA0ACaQIp7efoEqYWHuYQDcWA5YuyCgAKJ0vkqMkNMAKkpZ0JComDjAzE0kZJEcXDwI-EKOHJJNUAAciQwCgcEQQK2WBQKngh2OpwY5yuN0gAAVJLA0GoLp18pF3Kjbj80ABhGDQGTyRSqXFOLbiBY+AIGAD8wTsWwc0NojBYbARJzOl2ut3pwi0xMgpIp0CpLg8XhZy0csiOwuRorRmOI2PpESi4jw+DJxFmHjiVCoSFtuEou3Et3IxBoKFgbtJAEkeE00KACdLZZS0IzQMwqKBhLD4MRI8ylgYA-kCUDjCFzEDQAAybNKxaslRIW4WFC+UCdABMhuKXTdHpQ3t9-oJqS+pOEQakcoV+ZVBk27h27hNoDNFuMNGttqQ9uA2ywQA)

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it something like -

```
type TableRowsCells = Array<Record<string, string | number>>;
type SearchKey = string;

type EnhancedTableProps = {
  TableRowsCells: TableRowsCells,
  searchKey?: SearchKey;
};

function filterRows(
  rows: TableRowsCells,
  searchKey: SearchKey
) {
  return rows.filter((obj) =>
    Object.keys(obj).some((key) => obj[key].toString().includes(searchKey))
  );
}

function EnhancedTable({ TableRowsCells, searchKey }: EnhancedTableProps) {
  /** Code stuff...**/

  let outputRowsItems = TableRowsCells;
  if (typeof searchKey === 'string' && searchKey.length > 2) {
    outputRowsItems = filterRows(TableRowsCells, searchKey);
  }

  /** Code stuff...**/
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKghgIwDYQEoHsDuBnAwhJJbKAXigEEAnSuEAHlQgGN1KATO7YSgSwDsA5gBooXXoKgAfKHwCuAWwQRKAPhUBuAFChIUAMoQ4lJgAsA0hBClR3fgK3bw0AKJ8TcPkwht4yCAAVKdDBiMgBvTShYRBQMHHxCbAAuaL84vAIiIUjRQ2NzSwB%20FIMjUwsQLQBfBwAzWU9gHnQ%20KFqeJGBldIAKHKCcFN9YrAzE7KjsPPLLEumCkE0ASigIqMoIYFlKVoHsADp2zuUenvQEACsVkhUcqIB5S%20ZgfYBrS2wzy6X97HR5CCnd4ga4qKDnC4AbWBAF19sB0HpbIIej9%20EwkLI2BBPlMygslkscktqppNPVGs1Wq53J5vMNAWFUiN4plsCI8fkKlAqikaR4vD4YgEgiEVmsoAB6ABU0qguHQ2JsslqtX26tlkrJURQwHBsmAYAN6QAkl15KFmWhRgkiFoojxalAejoIOgnZyZlYSD6oAByMR2P1QABkIdy%20Iq%20xQgmAJigYIATOK7vrDcbRmaIBbrEcupRegz0rb2RGuZYSTkqtqpbL5YroFwVWqNdKtdWgA)

Comment: thank you for your reply. I solved the errors based on your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the type of the input, you need to use a generic type parameter for `filterRows`

```
function filterRows<T extends Record<keyof T, string>>(
  rows: Array<T>,
  searchKey: string
) {
  return rows.filter((obj) =>
    Object.keys(obj).some((key) => obj[key as keyof T].toString().includes(searchKey))
  );
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#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-Eru9HP13ogAGRHsczSdBA5SKBWRBVABMbjuzdb7bUXaNwtCmFwajkfb5QczguYQN3POYVlWIA)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, i still get errors. I updated the question body for more precisions. thx